# My BAT file does not execute my executable file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder with an exe inside. I am creating a BAT file to run it. Here is the code:

```
START "C:\Program Files\myApp\XYNTService.exe -i"
EXIT
```

But the exe seems does not being executed. Only the cmd window appear with the path `C:\Program Files\myApp`.

How to make the exe run with the `-i` flag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the `START` command sees something quoted, it assumes it is the title of the command window. The syntax of `START` looks like this:

```
START ["title"] [/Dpath] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED]
      [/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL]
      [/WAIT] [/B] [command/program]
      [parameters]

    "title"     Title to display in  window title bar.
...
```

So what you want to try is this:

```
START "" "C:\Program Files\myApp\XYNTService.exe" -i
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Run As Administrator for your BAT file.

Comment: this would do hassle to users.